# Firebird Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-embedded

I am using Firebird database and newly started with this database so I am implementing with Visual studio 2015. I am accessing a Firebird Embedded database using *ADO.NET* and my Firebird Embedded database file extension is *.CMP*. I am successfully using *ADO.NET*.

Now I want to use with Firebird Entity Framework. I have done a successful install. When I click entity data model and select the Firebird data source it opens connection properties where I select `server type =1(embedded)`.

This is my ADO.NET connection string:

```
string Connectionstring = "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:G\\CLINEDB.CMP;DataSource=localhost;Port=3050;Dialect=3; Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true; MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=1;"
```

When I click test connection it show this error:

> Unable to load DLL fbembed: the specified module could not be found

I have downloaded the embedded folder from Firebird and added it to the project solution so in advance option added 'Client Library as *fbclient.dll* file from project solution' for this I am getting error

> Connection lost to database

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you download the 32 bit or 64 bit embedded? What happens if you switch (from 32 bit to 64 bit, or from 64 bit to 32 bit)? As a workaround, you could also use a local installed Firebird server. BTW: It might be better to ask this on the firebird-net-provider mailing list.

Comment: thanks for reply i have use 64bit i getting error "Connection lost to Database" if i use 32bit i'm getting error "unsupported  on-disk structure for file .CMP found 11.1, support 12.0. IProvider::attachDatabase failed when loading mapping once."

Comment: That suggest that you should be using the 32 bit one and that your database has the On-Disk-Structure (ODS) of Firebird 2.1. Given Firebird 3 only supports its own ODS version (12), you should either use the Firebird 2.5 embedded, or upgrade your database to Firebird 3 as described in the Firebird 3 release notes.